# riak_core vnode distribution

Tags: erlang, riak

I have a setup with riak_core application on 2-node cluster. The template for the application was generated following https://github.com/rzezeski/try-try-try/tree/master/2011/riak-core-first-multinode

When I look at the distribution of vnodes across 2 nodes:

```
{ok, Ring} = riak_core_ring_manager:get_my_ring(), 
riak_core_ring:chash(ring).
```

, I'm getting this:

```
{64,
 [{0, 'node1@127.0.0.1'},
  {22835963083295358096932575511191922182123945984, 'node1@127.0.0.1'},
  {45671926166590716193865151022383844364247891968, 'node2@127.0.0.1'},
  {68507889249886074290797726533575766546371837952, 'node2@127.0.0.1'},
  {91343852333181432387730302044767688728495783936, 'node1@127.0.0.1'},
  {114179815416476790484662877555959610910619729920, 'node1@127.0.0.1'},
  {137015778499772148581595453067151533092743675904, 'node2@127.0.0.1'},
  {159851741583067506678528028578343455274867621888, 'node2@127.0.0.1'},
  {182687704666362864775460604089535377456991567872, 'node1@127.0.0.1'},
  {205523667749658222872393179600727299639115513856, 'node1@127.0.0.1'},
  {228359630832953580969325755111919221821239459840, 'node2@127.0.0.1'}, 
...............<the rest of vnodes>.......................
]
}
```

So vnodes go in pairs such that 2 adjacent partitions belong to the same physical node. From the documentation I'd expect the adjacent partitions to belong to different physical nodes. I'd appreciate if someone could elaborate on whether the above is a bug or feature, or maybe misconfiguration from my side.

Regards,
Boris

Comment: Riak documentation strongly suggests [a minimum of 5 nodes](http://basho.com/why-your-riak-cluster-should-have-at-least-five-nodes/).

Comment: Yes, but I wasn't sure if this recommendation applies to all riak_core applications in general. I'm not planning to use riak KV, but only riak_core alone for the specific distribution management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Riak_core will default to `target_n_val` of 4 (at https://github.com/basho/riak_core/blob/riak_core-0.14.2/ebin/riak_core.app#L73).  This is the preflist size used by the [riak_core_claim](https://github.com/basho/riak_core/blob/riak_core-0.14.2/src/riak_core_claim.erl) module.

The claim algorithm will try to ensure that in any chain of `target_n_val` consecutive vnodes that no 2 reside on the same node.

If you set target_n_val to 2 in your app.config it should do a better job of not putting adjacent vnodes on the same node.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I still don't fully understand: why would riak_core distribute vnodes in such a way that partitions do not reside on nodes in a natural way (or at least the way it's shown in multiple Riak books and documentation)? The amount of work that takes to proceed handoffs from one node to another when going from 1-node to 2-node setup seems to be the same.

Comment: You should have received `WARNING: Not all replicas will be on distinct nodes` when you ran `riak-admin cluster plan` to let you know that the claim algorithm was not able ensure that no nodes were duplicated in a preflist.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the distribution where all adjacent vnodes reside on different physical nodes, by setting:

```
{wants_claim_fun, {riak_core_claim, wants_claim_v3}},
{choose_claim_fun, {riak_core_claim, choose_claim_v3}}
```

for riak_core app.

'target_n_val' does not seem to affect the distribution in this case.